# Combining postgres query and log duration

Tags: postgresql

I am aware that you can show the duration and log queries using the configuration below in postgresql.conf

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CUSTOMIZED OPTIONS
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

log_statement = 'all'
log_duration = on
log_line_prefix = '{"Time":[%t], Host:%h} '
```

And then returns logs like

```
{"Time":[2018-08-13 16:24:20 +08], Host:172.18.0.2} LOG:  statement: SELECT "auth_user"."id", "auth_user"."password", "auth_user"."last_login", "auth_user"."is_superuser", "auth_user"."username", "auth_user"."first_name", "auth_user"."last_name", "auth_user"."email", "auth_user"."is_staff", "auth_user"."is_active", "auth_user"."date_joined" FROM "auth_user" WHERE "auth_user"."id" = 1
{"Time":[2018-08-13 16:24:20 +08], Host:172.18.0.2} LOG:  duration: 7.694 ms
```

But can I combine the duration and statement in a single line like?

```
LOG: { statement: ..., duration: 7.694 ms}
```

Comment: Did you try `log_min_duration_statement = 0`?

Comment: Your answer is so perfect!!!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way you are logging, the statement is logged when the server starts processing it, but the duration is only known at the end of the execution.

This is why it has to be logged as two different messages.

If you use `log_min_duration_statement = 0` instead, the statement is logged at the end of execution together with the duration.