# Get postgres query log statement and duration as one record

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have `log_min_duration_statement=0` in  config.

When I check log file, sql statement and duration are saved into different rows.
(Not sure what I have wrong, but statement and duration are not saved together as [this answer points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51836447/1609729))

As I understand `session_line_num` for duration record  always equals to `session_line_num + 1` for relevant statement, for same session of course.

Is this correct? is below query reliable to correctly get statement with duration in one row?

(csv log imported into `postgres_log` table):

```
WITH 
sql_cte AS(
    SELECT session_id, session_line_num, message AS sql_statement
    FROM postgres_log
    WHERE
    message LIKE 'statement%'
)
,durat_cte AS (
    SELECT session_id, session_line_num, message AS duration 
    FROM postgres_log
    WHERE
    message LIKE 'duration%'
)
SELECT 
t1.session_id,
t1.session_line_num,
t1.sql_statement,
t2.duration
FROM sql_cte t1
LEFT JOIN durat_cte t2 
ON t1.session_id = t2.session_id AND t1.session_line_num + 1 = t2.session_line_num;
```

Comment: Assuming this is true: *session_line_num for duration record always equals to session_line_num + 1 for relevant statement* then that query looks ok. But that behavior seems like a very strange denormalization of the system tables

Comment: You could try `lag(message) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id ORDER BY session_line_num) AS prev_msg`

Comment: @Z4-tier - That's the problem, I'm not sure if that should be assumed or not

Comment: @wildplasser - Seems better idea, thanks for that

Comment: And you should possibly join/partition them by session_transaction_id, too.

Comment: @wildplasser - Is that needed? because as doc ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html ) shows `session_id, session_line_num` is unique (PK for csv log table)

Comment: It is not important. The logfile is in fact a denormalisation of session -->> {transaction/statement} -->> {message}. And the line numbers start at session-start, not at transaction-start.

Comment: @z4tier It isn't a system table.  It is a text log file which has apparently been manually imported into the system.